# Click on a button using mail rule & Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, mail.app

I wrote this to push on a button, and it's work fine when I run the script,
however when I run the script from mail (trigger from a email rule) nothing happen.

Is this due to an Applescript limitation or am I doing something wrong?

```
try
    activate application "app"
on error
    delay 1
    activate application "app"
end try

delay 0.5

try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "app"
            click button 2 of window 1

        end tell
    end tell
on error
    --
end try
```

Comment: Just putting this here if you end up needing a debugger to look at the values of the variables in your AppleScript - https://latenightsw.com

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what application is "app", as it is its button that you are trying to activate, or do what bmike suggests and get a high end script editor, like Script Debugger.

Comment: it's an internal app , it's weirdly work very fine when the script is executed from the Script editor, anyway I will try to have some debug info and leave more details